# Multiply consecutive numbers in list?

Tags: python, loops

I have the following list:

```
list1 = [1, 5, 7, 13, 29, 35, 65, 91, 145, 203, 377, 455, 1015, 1885, 2639, 13195]
```

How do I multiply every number in the list? For example `1 * 5 * 7 * 13 * 29..etc`.

Am I on the correct track with the code below?:

```
for numbs in list1:
    numbs * list1[#iterate through list1, starting on 2nd item in list1]
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest approach here would be to use a `reduce` operation which does exactly this:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

reduce(operator.mul, [1, 2, 3])
>>> 6
```

Reduce is basically saying: Apply this operation to index 0 and 1. Take the result and then apply the operation to that result and index 2. So on an so forth.

`operator.mul` is just a small amount of syntactic sugar for representing multiplication and it could easily be replaced with another function.

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
reduce(multiply, [1,2,3])
```

This will do exactly the same thing.

The reduce function is available as a built in in Python 2 but [it was removed and is only available in functools in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Making sure to import reduce will ensure Python 2/3 compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

As alternatives the `operator` module and `operator.mul`, you can do this:

- a basic for-loop:

  ```
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  product = 1
  for item in list1:
      product *= item
  print(product)           #  120
  ```
- use the `numpy` module:

  ```
  from numpy import prod
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  print(prod(list1))       #  120
  ```
- importing `functools` and apply a lambda-function:

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list1))      #  120
  ```

  **or**

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  prodFunc = lambda x, y: x * y
  print(reduce(prodFunc, list1))      #  120
  ```

  **or**, without lambda:

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  def prodFunc(a,b):
      return a * b
  print(reduce(prodFunc, list1))      #  120
  ```